# Search all Excel worksheets in workbook from Access with string from form on event with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

The code below opens an Excel spreadsheet from a button event on an Access form, and searches for a string in a form control on a named Worksheet. I would like to adapt this code to search through all Worksheets. The excel workbook is a variable lifted from a form control.

````
```
Private Sub Command132_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_Command132_Click

Dim filename As String
Dim searchstring As String

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application 'Excel object
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook 'Workbook object
Dim Xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet 'Worksheet object


Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
searchstring = Me.Matrixsrch
filename = Me.GroupsMatrixLoccntrl
Set XlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Set Xlsheet = XlBook.Sheets("GroupMatrix")
With Xlsheet
         .Cells.Find(What:=searchstring, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlvalues, LookAt:=xlPart, 
 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End With

Exit_Command132_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command132_Click:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & "; " & Err.Description
    Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & "; " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command132_Click

End Sub
````

```
 I have tried using the code below to iterate through the worksheets. The search is run on the first worksheet and a value found, but subsequently an *Error 91; Object variable or With block variable not set* is generated. Can anyone help me with the iteration please? thanks
```

```
    For Each Xlsheet In XlBook.Worksheets
With Xlsheet
         .Cells.Find(What:=searchstring, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlvalues, LookAt:=xlPart, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End With
Next
```

Comment: You need to test if the find was successful.

Comment: Thankyou. Yes, if a matching value is present on the 1st sheet it is found, and then the error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test if the find was successful.

If it was, then exit the loop (assuming you want to stop after the `searchstring` is found; if this is not the case, remove the `Exit For`.)

```
For Each Xlsheet In XlBook.Worksheets
    With Xlsheet
        Dim foundCell as Range
        Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=searchstring, _
                                    After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False, _
                                    SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
             .Activate
             foundCell.Select
             Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: I tagged out `Exit for` and edited `SearchFormat:=False)` to  ` SearchFormat:=False) _
                                    .Activate`                                     If the value is present on the 1st sheet the search finds and selects the relevant cell and a `Error 424; Object required` error is shown. If the value is not present on the 1st sheet (and is present on the 2nd) the search stops and a  `Error 91; Object variable or With block variable not set` is shown

Comment: Don't `Activate` - you don't need to. If you really want to, you should work with `foundCell`, as my comment says. If you chain the `.Activate` as you are currently doing, you'll get an error if the find fails, which is exactly your current problem.

Comment: sorry for being slow but how do I know if the search has run if I dont activate?

Comment: Do whatever with `FoundCell` - `Debug.Print foundCell.Address` for example. Unless your end goal is to activate that cell...

Comment: yes I want the screen focus to shift to that cell so the user can see it

Comment: Edited the answer.